# How to secure private repositories?

Tags: git, security, github

I‘m curious if big companies like Microsoft, Facebook or game studios use GitHub private repositories for their source code? Do they use own hosted Git server instead? I‘m just thinking if private repositories of GitHub are really private and secure? I mean, if you upload the code of an app, pc Game or web application of high value, is it a good idea to use GitHub or would you recommend to setup an own git service?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many companies, including the company I work for with around 400 developers, use an internally hosted instance of a git manager. Our company uses Bitbucket. No one outside the company's network can access the repositories.

Private repositories aren't really an option when you are dealing with hundreds of developers and needing features that aren't provided to with free accounts.

If there is sensitive or proprietary code/data being uploaded, having an internal instance is much more secure. There are also many other options. You can host these instances in the cloud, which in theory is just as secure as hosting it on site.